# Thailand consulate asking for an impossible document

Tags: visas, paperwork, tourist-visas, hong-kong

I am currently an exchange student in Hong Kong. Once I finish my studies, I plan to travel a bit around Asia and visit Thailand, Japan, and Malaysia. So far, I've received both the Japanese and the Malaysian visas with no problems. However, I'm having a strange problem with the Thailand consulate.

They told me that for holders of my passport, I'm required to provide a guarantee letter from my university that states that my university **knows** I am travelling to Thailand and that they are **responsible** for what I do there. I told the consulate lady that there is no way a university would issue such a paper because they simply can't be held responsible for what a student would do in a country. I also told her that I have evidence of booked return flights that are non refundable, and hotel reservations for the period that are also non refundable. The lady just insisted that I have to get the document or my visa application will not be accepted.

I went back to my university and tried, but as expected, the university refused to issue such a paper since it is not their responsibility of where I travel They said the best they can do is to say that I am a student.

Now, I am not sure what I am supposed to do. The consulate lady is literally asking for a document that is impossible to be issued. Can I do anything about this? Is there any place that I can reach that might help me with this? It just sounds ridiculous that a consulate would ask for a document that is impossible to be issued!

Comment: Get that document which the university is offering you and then try to submit your application with another clerk.

Comment: Is there not some sort of confusion on the type of visa and/or the purpose of your stay? It seems like they think you are going there on some sort of school-organised trip. Can you clarify the type of visa you have requested, and your citizenship?

Comment: From what I gather, you are supposed to provide a letter confirming your status (I.e. that you are enrolled). Not sure where the additional requirements come from...

Comment: "Once I finish my studies, " If you're going after you finish your studies, you won't be a student anymore. The university shouldn't even be able to provide a document stating you're a student. You should try mentioning this.

Comment: The lunatics have taken over the asylum.

Comment: Try to contact her supervisor, or even the MoFA directly.

Comment: As your exchange program will have ended, are they asking for acknowledgement by your home-country (or residence) uni?

Comment: Something must be wrong. Just apply for a tourist visa. Don't mention anything about your studies.

Comment: For some nationalities, one has to provide a "proof of status", either from their employer (if employed) or from their school (if a student), no that's not an option. But it should just state that the student is currently enrolled, not ask for the school to take responsibility or anything like that.

Answer (score 7):

It's possible that the Thai clerk that is processing your visa application got the impression somehow that you're traveling for academic purposes.  Is this the case?  If it is, it's possible that this letter is required, and if you can't get such a letter, you will have to change your plans to exclude Thailand.

If your travel is strictly personal and has nothing to do with your education, make sure that your visa application states this, and try your application again.